Get camera calibration matrix data on iPhone in Expo app
I am using the expo-camera library for my Expo app to capture photos using the device's camera.
When run on the physical iPhone device, how can the camera calibration data (intrinsic matrix, lens distortion, etc) be access from the Expo app?
